# Best way to refactor If-statement

Tags: if-statement, coding-style, refactoring

I have the following code:

```
                            if (adSetting.Core_standard_application_role)
                            {
                                rc = new IntegrationRoleCompany();
                                rc.RoleCompany = firmSettings.FirmNo.ToString();
                                rc.RoleName = "Core standard application role";
                                rcList.Add(rc);
                            }
                            if (adSetting.Expense_Invoice_Application_Access)
                            {
                                rc = new IntegrationRoleCompany();
                                rc.RoleCompany = firmSettings.FirmNo.ToString();
                                rc.RoleName = "Expense Invoice Application Access";
                                rcList.Add(rc);
                            }
```

The problem is that I have 20 if-checks where I check addSetting.Property. Now to the question:

What is the best and most effective way to refactor this if-statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have a 20x2 array with the adSetting.STUFF_AS_STRING -> rc.RoleName mapping.

then loop over the array in a for loop

pseudo code:

```
for (var i=0; i<theArray.length; i++) {
    adSettingStr, RoleName = theArray[i]
    if (adSetting[adSettingStr]) {
        rc = new IntegrationRoleCompany();
        rc.RoleCompany = firmSettings.FirmNo.ToString();
        rc.RoleName = RoleName;
        rcList.Add(rc);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, smart solution :)

Comment: you are welcome... it is the first time I see a 'language independent question... very interesting compare to the standard "why doesn't X work"